# Finding a root of an equation effectively in python

Tags: python, scipy

I need to find the root of an equation in python, for a different set of parameters and I am not sure what is the most effective way to do so. Here is an example of what I need (and tried so far).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

a = np.array([2,3])
for i in a:
    def func(y):
        return i - 1/y

    x0 = fsolve(func, 0.3)
    print (x0)
```

So in this case I want to find the root of that equation for 2 different values of my parameter a (of course in my actual case the function is more complicated and I have a lot of values for the parameter a, not just 2). This works, but that for function doesn't seem a very good idea for a lot of values of a. Is there a faster (numpy?) way of doing this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend vectorization, try below code.

```
a = np.array([2,3])

def func(y):
    return a - 1/y 

length_a = len(a)

x0 = fsolve(func, np.ones(length_a)*0.3)
```